# simplify multiple (30 columns) column complex pyspark aggregation in one go

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aggregation

I have a sample spark df as below:

```
df = ([[1, 'a', 'b' , 'c'],
      [1, 'b', 'c' , 'b'],
      [1, 'b', 'a' , 'b'],
      [2, 'c', 'a' , 'a'],
      [3, 'b', 'b' , 'a']]).toDF(['id', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3'])
```

What I need next is to provide a multiple aggregations to show summary of the a, b, c values for each field. I have a working but tedious process as below:

```
agg_table = (
  df
        .groupBy('id') 
        .agg(
          # field1
             sum(when(col('field1') == 'a',1).otherwise(0)).alias('field1_a_count')
             ,sum(when(col('field1') == 'b',1).otherwise(0)).alias('field1_b_count')
             ,sum(when(col('field1') == 'c',1).otherwise(0)).alias('field1_c_count')
          # field2
             ,sum(when(col('field2') == 'a',1).otherwise(0)).alias('field2_a_count')
             ,sum(when(col('field2') == 'b',1).otherwise(0)).alias('field2_b_count')
             ,sum(when(col('field2') == 'c',1).otherwise(0)).alias('field2_c_count')
          # field3
             ,sum(when(col('field3') == 'a',1).otherwise(0)).alias('field3_a_count')
             ,sum(when(col('field3') == 'b',1).otherwise(0)).alias('field3_b_count')
             ,sum(when(col('field3') == 'c',1).otherwise(0)).alias('field3_c_count')
         ))
```

What I am expecting to get is this:

```
agg_table = (['id':'1','2','3'],
             ['field1_a_count':1,0,0],
             ['field1_b_count':2,0,1],
             ['field1_c_count':0, 1, 0],
             ['field2_a_count':1,1,0],
             ['field2_b_count':1,0,1],
             ['field2_c_count':1,0,0],
             ['field3_a_count':0,1,1],
             ['field3_b_count':2,0,0],
             ['field3_c_count':1,0,0])
```

It is just fine if I only really have 3 fields, but I have 30 fields with varying/custom names. Maybe somebody can help me with the repetitive task of coding the aggregated sum per field. I tried playing around with a suggestion from :
https://danvatterott.com/blog/2018/09/06/python-aggregate-udfs-in-pyspark/

I can make it work if I will only pull one column and one value, but I get varying errors, one of them is:

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`value`' given input columns: ['field1','field2','field3']
```

One last line I tried is using:

```
validated_cols = ['field1','field2','field3']

df.select(validated_cols).groupBy('id').agg(collect_list($'field1_a_count',$'field1_b_count',$'field1_c_count', ...
 
 $'field30_c_count')).show()

Output: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried with pivot too, but from searches so far, it says it is only good for one column. I tried this multiple columns:

```
df.withColumn("p", concat($"p1", $"p2"))
  .groupBy("a", "b")
  .pivot("p")
  .agg(...)
```

I still get a syntax error.

Another link I tried: https://danvatterott.com/blog/2019/02/05/complex-aggregations-in-pyspark/

I also tried the exprs approach: `exprs1 = {x: "sum" for x in df.columns if x != 'id'}`

Any suggested will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Let me answer your question in two steps. First, you are wondering if it is possible to avoid hard coding all your aggregations in your attempt to compute all your aggregations. It is. I would do it like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

# let's assume that this is known, but we could compute it as well
values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
# All the columns except the id
cols = [ c for c in df.columns if c != 'id' ]

def count_values(column, value):
    return f.sum(f.when(f.col(column) == value, 1).otherwise(0))\
            .alias(f"{column}_{value}_count")

# And this gives you the result of your hard coded aggregations:
df\
    .groupBy('id')\
    .agg(*[count_values(c, value) for c in cols for value in values])\
    .show()
```

But that is not what you expect right? You are trying to compute some kind of pivot on the `id` column. To do this, I would not use the previous result, but just work the data differently. I would start by replacing all the columns of the dataframe but `id` (that is renamed into `x`) by an array of values of the form `{column_name}_{value}_count`, and I would explode that array. From there, we just need to compute a simple pivot on the former `id` column renamed `x`, grouped by the values contained in the exploded array.

```py
df\
    .select(f.col('id').alias('x'), f.explode(
         f.array(
             [f.concat_ws('_', f.lit(c), f.col(c), f.lit('count')).alias(c)
                 for c in cols]
         )
    ).alias('id'))\
    .groupBy('id')\
    .pivot('x')\
    .count()\
    .na.fill(0)\
    .orderBy('id')\
    .show()
```

which yields:

```
+--------------+---+---+---+
|            id|  1|  2|  3|
+--------------+---+---+---+
|field1_a_count|  1|  0|  0|
|field1_b_count|  2|  0|  1|
|field1_c_count|  0|  1|  0|
|field2_a_count|  1|  1|  0|
|field2_b_count|  1|  0|  1|
|field2_c_count|  1|  0|  0|
|field3_a_count|  0|  1|  1|
|field3_b_count|  2|  0|  0|
|field3_c_count|  1|  0|  0|
+--------------+---+---+---+
```

Comment: This answers the question, but do you think this question hints at a deeper problem with the way the data is being modeled?

Comment: I modified your code to fit my dataset but it did not give me the intended result. However, I like your suggested function where you had the three values collected into a single function. Earlier, after playing around, I came up with three functions: 1. collect a 2. collect b 3. collect c then aggregate the results. I will definitely play around your function definition. Thanks

Comment: Thanks :) Don't hesitate let me know what's missing. You may for instance update your question, or ask another one and let me know (because I won't get a notification), and I'll see if I can improve the answer.
@z4-tier For the first version, I don't think so, that's just an aggregation of statistics. For the second one however, it clearly won't work if there are too many distinct `id`s.

Comment: Thank you. You beat me to it! I thought of revising the question.

Answer (score 1):

#### update

based on discussion in the comments, I think this question is a case of an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The task at hand is something that is seen very frequently in the world of Data Engineering and ETL development: how to partition and then quantify good and bad records.

In the case where the data is being prepared to load to a data warehouse / hadoop ecosystem, the usual pattern is to take the raw input and load it to a dataframe, then apply transformations & validations that partition the data into "The Good, The Bad, and The Ugly":

- The first— and hopefully largest— partition contains records that are successfully transformed and which pass validation. These will go on to be persisted in durable storage and certified to be used for anayltics.
- The second partition contains records that were successfully transformed but which failed during QA. The QA rules should include checks for illegal nulls, string pattern matching (like phone number format), etc...
- The third partition is for records that are rejected early in the process because they failed on a transformation step. Examples include fields that contain non-number values that are cast to numeric types, text fields that exceed the maximum length, or strings that contain control characters that are not supported by the database.

The goal **should not** be to generate counts for each of these 3 classifications across every column and for every row. Trying to do that is counterproductive. Why? Because when a transformation step or QA check fails for a given record, that entire record should be rejected immediately and sent to a separate output stream to be analyzed later. Each row in the data set should be treated as just that: a single record. It isn't possible for a single field to fail and still have the complete record pass, which makes metrics at this granularity unnecessary. What action will you take knowing that 100 rows passed on the "address" field? For valid records, all that matters is the total number that passed for every column. Otherwise, it wouldn't be a valid record.

With that said, remember that the goal is to build a usable and cleansed data set; analyzing the rejected records is a secondary task and can be done offline.

It is common practice to add a field to the rejected data to indicated which column caused the failure. That makes it easy to troubleshoot any malformed data, so there is really no need to generate counts across all columns, even for bad records. Instead, just review the rejected data after the main job finishes, and address the problems. Continue doing that iteratively until the number of rejected records is below whatever threshold you think is reasonable, and then continue to monitor it going forward.

---

##### Old answer

This is a sign of a design flaw in the data. Whatever the "field1", "field2", etc... columns actually represent, it appears they are all related, in the sense that the values quantify some attribute (maybe each one is a count for a specific merchandise ID, or the number of people with a certain property...). The problem is that these fields are being added as individual columns on a fact table<sup>1</sup>, which then needs to be aggregated, resulting in the situation that you're facing.

A better design would be to collapse those "field1", "field2", etc... columns into a single code field that can be used as the `GROUP BY` field when doing the aggregation. You might want to consider creating a separate table to do this if the existing one has many other columns and making this change would alter the grain in a way that might cause other problems.

---

<sup>1: it's usually a big red flag to have a table with a bunch of enumerated columns with the same name and purpose. I've even seen cases where someone has created tables with "spare" columns for when they want to add more attributes later. Not good.</sup>

Comment: I like your thought process though I partially understand. let us say these are the fields: `'id','firstname','lastname', 'streetaddress', 'state'`. Each field has been flagged as `'valid', 'invalid', 'missing'`. In the succeeding table, each column will be just counts of valids, invalids, missing.  Can you show me a sample separate table code you are suggesting? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is to have 3 counters for each column in the input so you can track the valid/invalid/missing status. A dataframe is not the right tool for that task. I would use a native python dictionary that maps the name of each column in the input dataframe to a list with 3 integers that you can use as counters while you apply the data validation rules.

Comment: You beat me to it! That is what I am thinking as of current! Honestly, I am googling how to do it. Any leads?

Comment: It sounds like you're really trying to quantify what happens during a data cleansing and transformation process. In that case, i sense that you might be overthinking things. There should not be any reason to require valid/invalid/missing counts on every input column, since a record is only valid if *all of it's fields are valid*. Bad records should be sent to the error table immediately, and analyzed later. I updated this answer to give more details.